# CamelContextStartedEvent called twice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

The `CamelContextStartedEvent` is called twice for the same camel context (camel-1). The issue might be the way I register the `EventNotifier`. You can reproduce the issue with Spring Initializr with Spring Boot 1.5.14, Spring Boot Camel Starter 2.21.1 and Spring Boot Web Starter.

See the logs:

```
2018-07-06 11:04:41.104  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2018-07-06 11:04:41.106  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.c.m.ManagedManagementStrategy        : JMX is enabled
2018-07-06 11:04:41.191  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2018-07-06 11:04:41.193  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector    : Starting CamelMainRunController to ensure the main thread keeps running
2018-07-06 11:04:41.193  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started
2018-07-06 11:04:41.194  INFO 19092 --- [           main] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.21.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.090 seconds
2018-07-06 11:04:41.195  INFO 19092 --- [           main] c.e.bug.service.StartupEventNotifier     : CamelContextStartedEvent for SpringCamelContext(camel-1) with spring id application:11223
2018-07-06 11:04:41.195  INFO 19092 --- [           main] c.e.bug.service.StartupEventNotifier     : CamelContextStartedEvent for SpringCamelContext(camel-1) with spring id application:11223
2018-07-06 11:04:41.216  INFO 19092 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 11223 (http)
2018-07-06 11:04:41.221  INFO 19092 --- [           main] com.example.bug.BugApplication           : Started BugApplication in 4.684 seconds (JVM running for 6.773)
```

The service that initializes the `EventNotifier`:

```
@Service
public class SchedulerService {

    private final CamelContext camelContext;

    private final StartupEventNotifier startupEventNotifier;

    public SchedulerService(CamelContext camelContext, StartupEventNotifier startupEventNotifier) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;
        this.startupEventNotifier = startupEventNotifier;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(startupEventNotifier);
    }

}
```

The `EventNotifier`:

```
@Component
public class StartupEventNotifier extends EventNotifierSupport {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartupEventNotifier.class);

    @Override
    public void notify(EventObject event) throws Exception {
        if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
            logger.info("CamelContextStartedEvent for {}", event.getSource());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(EventObject event) {
        if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
camel:
  springboot:
    main-run-controller: true
server:
  port: 11223
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to register it yourself. Camel scans for all implementations of `EventNotifier` in bean registry automatically. I think it is registered once by Camel and once by you.

Comment: I'll check next week and let you know. Thx for the quick answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called twice, because it is registered twice. Once by you and once by Apache Camel. `EventNotifier` is registered automatically, if is found in `Registry`. Since your `StartupEventNotifier` is annotated as `Component`, it is part of `Registry` and Apache Camel registered it during `CamelContext` startup *(You can see it in [`CamelAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.21.x/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.java) line 424)*.

**You have four options:**

- Remove your custom registration from `SchedulerService`.
- Remove `@Component` annotation from `StartupEventNotifier` and register it with with `camelContext.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(new StartupEventNotifier())`
- Add duplicity check to your `SchedulerService`. Something like:

  ```
  if (!context.getManagementStrategy().getEventNotifiers().contains(startupEventNotifier)){
      context.getManagementStrategy().addEventNotifier(startupEventNotifier);
  }
  ```
- Register `EventNotifier` in `@PostConstruct` of `RouteBuilder`. It will be registered before automatic discovery is started and then it will be skipped in [`CamelAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.21.x/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.java) *(See line 422)*